# when we create table directly from java in ms access,"Null" occurs

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

when i create table directly from java in ms access,"Null" occurs.What is meant by this [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

It means that there was an `Exception` thrown:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 null
```

Which is caused by an infinite loop - StackOverflow. You have to change the heap size. This can be done by running your application with:

```
java -Xmx1g myprogram
```

You can increase the value (1g is 1GB, 14g will be 14GB) as you wish as long as you have enough memory available.

Also, you can add `;memory = false` to the end of the url with which you connect to the db.

Comment: would you please guide me in  a simple way because i am new in java so i am not  getting properly what you are saying

Comment: What IDE do you use? It looks like you want to process to much data at once.

Comment: I can't navigate on it, but you have to find the run configuration and add system variable -Xmx1g

Comment: what's this Xmx1g?

Comment: Variable which will tell your JVM to allocate more memory for the heap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124220/discussion-between-mcolo-and-xenteros).

Answer (score -1):

You can counter this by using this with your code

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:Database.accdb memory=false");
```

and then go to your ms access database file and open it and go to Database Tool and `Click to Compact and repair option.`

Comment: You are missing the semi-colon (`;`) before `memory`.